# What role does "tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper" play over "tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell"

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In many places of implementing BasicRNNCell it is found that code using:

```
tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
    tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units= num_neurons , activation=tf.nn.relu), 
    output_size=num_outputs)
```

What does "OutputProjectionWrapper" is doing over "BasicRNNCell"

As per the code seen for implementation of "tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell" the call function it return the output of RNN . We can directly proceed by using its call function.

```
# Creating the Model

num_inputs = 1
num_neurons = 100
num_outputs = 1
learning_rate = 0.005
num_train_iterations = 2000
batch_size = 1


tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_time_steps, num_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_time_steps, num_outputs])

# Using Basic RNN Model

cell= tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=num_neurons,activation=tf.nn.relu),output_size=num_outputs)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

# MEAN SQUARED ERROR
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

I expected that we can directly pass BasicRNNCell to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` but before this step what `OutputProjectionWrapper` is doing is completely unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass  BasicRNNCell to tf.nn.dynamic_rnn directly or you can add a projection layer to BasicRNNCell before paasing it to tf.nn.dynamic_rnn. What OutputProjectionWrapper does is that it adds a dense layer after the output of the RNN.